# Why does my MongoDB compass keeps loading in activating plugins screen?

Tags: mongodb

When I try to start my MongoDB Compass updated version, it keeps on loading stating Activating plugins.I have updated the compass and using the latest version of it but still facing this issue. [I have added the MongoDB compass screen image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdfRP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Me too had the same problem before. After that i downloaded the compass ISOLATED edition, all run well afterthat..